# Python list[i] error

Tags: python-3.x

I want to find even numbers with Python 3. I made a list and filled it up and `list[i]` worked, but when I try to find out the even numbers. I can't query the list.

```
list = {}
x = 1
while (x <= 10):
    list[x]=x
    x+=1

for x in range(10):
    if( list[x] %2 == 0): print(x)
```

Comment: you should init `x=0` or change to `for x in range(1,10)` keep in mind range is from 1 to 9 if you want 10 to be counted use `range(1,11)`

Comment: `range` default `start` is 0, your dict (terribly name as `list`) contains keys 1 to 10, but the `range` loops through 0 to 9. Key 0 doesn't exist in your dict (`list`). You can change your `range` to `range(1, 11)` and the problem should go away.

Comment: you've created a dictionary not a list

Comment: thanks, it works now

Comment: @nyi: please `do` `not` use `code` ticks `for` text that is `not` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = []
x = 0
while (x <= 10):
    list.append(x)
    x+=1
for x in range(10):
    if( list[x] %2 == 0): 
        print(list[x])
```

use list `append` for adding items into list

Comment: no problem, your solution just needs an edit to the initialization of `x`